# SynchronizingObject for an event

Tags: c#, user-interface, events, multithreading

With `Timer` objects, I can set the `SynchronizingObject` property to avoid having to use invoke when updating the GUI from the timer's event handler. If I have a class that instead subscribes to an event and has to update the GUI in the event handler, is there an analogous concept? Or do I have to write the InvokeRequired boilerplate code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SynchronizingObject` is just an [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) property. (That interface is implemented by WinForms controls, for example.)

You can use the same interface yourself, although with a vanilla event there's nowhere to really specify the synchronization object.

What you *could* do is write a utility method which takes a delegate and an `ISynchronizeInvoke`, and returns a delegate which makes sure the original delegate is run on the right thread.

For example:

```
public static EventHandler<T> Wrap<T>(EventHandler<T> original,
    ISynchronizeInvoke synchronizingObject) where T : EventArgs
{
    return (object sender, T args) =>
    {
        if (synchronizingObject.InvokeRequired)
        {
            synchronizingObject.Invoke(original, new object[] { sender, args });
        }
        else
        {
            original(sender, args);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Is this class appropriate to use when I want to synchronize with a self-defined class (not winforms) as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10654163/328397

Comment: @makerofthings7: I don't think it's the approach I'd use in that case, no. If you're using .NET 4, look at what the TPL provides.

Answer (score -1):

You may take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.